# What is the purpose and meaning of (char)i or (int)i in java?

Tags: java

From this example

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("lalu.txt");
int i=0;

while(i=fis.read() !=-1){
    System.out.println((char)i);  
}
```

My purpose to ask this question is why the `char` is wrapped in parentheses here?

Comment: it is called casting read for more info http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java

Comment: Google on 'Java type casting'

Answer (score 3):

> why the char is wrapped in parentheses here?

Whoa, some magic happens here? Nope, it's very common in Java, known as *Explicit Type Casting*.

A cast expression converts, at run time, a value of one numeric type to a similar value of another numeric type; or confirms, at compile time, that the type of an expression is boolean; or checks, at run time, that a reference value refers to an object whose class is compatible with a specified reference type.

The parentheses and the type they contain are sometimes called the cast operator.

```
CastExpression:
( PrimitiveType ) UnaryExpression
( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

As you declare `i` as an `int` and you cast it `char` (in the parenthesis you write *char*) which means you are doing [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

According to §5.1.3:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

By default, the `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, and the `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character(reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)), which means

- int is 4 bytes, and
- char is 2 byte (Unicode character).

So, when you narrowing *integer* to *character* by explicit casting, you just simply telling the compiler to discard the first two byte from the integer and treat `i` as a character!

Let's see with an example:

```
int i = 0x41990041; // hex 41990041 is equivalent to decimal 1100546113
System.out.println("printing integer: " + i);
System.out.println("printing char representation of int: " +(char)i);
```

The output is:

> printing integer: 1100546113
>
> printing char representation of int: A

Here, I took a random 4 bytes value into integer `i`. Look carefully, the first two bytes `4199` is discarded when the casting performed in run time and the last two bytes `0041` is printed as character. See [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) the character representation of `hex` value `0041` is `A`.

Answer (score 0):

first they are not brackets they are parentheses.

the parentheses are there because this is how compiler understands that you are casting it to other. else it will throw compile time error.

Comment: try running as (char(i)) and compiler will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

A type name in parentheses, followed by a variable, (such as your `(char) i`) is called a 'type cast'. It tells the compiler, "Treat this variable as this type instead of its variable type", i.e. read `i` as a character instead of an integer. You have to start with `i` being an integer because there is no character numbered `-1` to show when the end of file is reached. After it is compared with `-1`, it can be casted (changed) to a `char`, because that is what the variable truly represents. For instance, if the first character of your file was `'N'`, `i` would be set to `'N'`'s [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) value, 78. `(char) i` changes 78 back to `'N'`. `System.out.println(i)` in this instance would print `78` instead of `N`.

To simplify, this is called type casting. It tells the compiler to read a variable as a different type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Java `char` type holds one Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. ASCII is not relevant to the code but, by the design of Unicode, 78 is the same ['LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/004e/index.htm).